# Calculating effect size of wilcoxon test after correction for multiple comparisons using R

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, effect-size, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am trying to compare two amino acid concentrations after two treatment variations. The data is not normal distributed, so I have to use non-parametric tests. I calculated the adjusted p values, but now I want the effect size as well. Is there an option to calculate the effect size for the adjusted p values?

I used the Wilcox_test function to get the p values.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(aminoacid) %>%
  wilcox_test(Concentraition ~ Treatment, paired = TRUE) %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "holm")
```

There is a function to calculate the effect sizes from the coin library, but it does not give me the option to correct for multiple comparison.

```r
 df %>% 
  group_by(aminoacid) %>%
  wilcox_effsize(Concentraition ~ Treatment, paired = TRUE)
```

Any idea for a solution? Could not find anything on that specific topic

EDIT:

I added a boxplot of my data. We took a blood sample from 18 individuals after each treatment. Every individual took both treatment options with 7-14 days apart.

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps describe or show your data in some way, say with plots of observations colored by treatment, for each of the amino acids? I'm not sure that a paired Wilcoxon test is appropriate; the "effect size" of the test is based on an assumption of normality for the non-parametric statistic and thus not as interesting as the actual differences in concentrations; there might be better ways to deal with the non-normality of the data. Also, unlike Bonferroni, there is no simple Holm-type adjustment for Ci; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/420849/28500).

Comment: Please, the famous software is called R, not r. Edited!

Comment: Thanks EdM for your prompt reply. I added a box plot to my question. I was actually pleased with the results from the wilcoxon test. Is it better to just leave the effect size? The test results gave me significant differences for some of the aminoacids - after holm correction the Amino acid TYR and TRP still is significant, which was surprising for me since both treatments should only be affecting TRP. I hence wanted to get some more information (like effect size) to discuss the results.

Comment: A few notes, that may be an answer:  a) I believe the function `wilcox_effsize` you are using is from the *rstatix* package, not the *coin* package.  b) I recommend using the matched-pairs rank biserial correlation coefficient rather than this "r" statistic for the effect size.  It is included in King, Rosopa, and Minimum (2000), and is simple enough to calculate or you can find an R function for it.  c) Corrections for multiple test don't apply to effect size statistics.

Answer (score 1):

- To answer what I think is the essence of the question, corrections for multiple tests don't apply to effect size statistics.
- As a general comment, I would recommend using the matched-pairs rank biserial correlation coefficient rather than the "r" statistic for the effect size. It is included in King, Rosopa, and Minimum (2000), and is simple enough to calculate. The only implementation I know of in R is from the *rcompanion* package, of which I am the author. The discussion of how to calculate these statistics becomes somewhat complicated based on how ties should be handled.  You might consider the following example with tied differences. You can change how ties are handled in these functions.

  ```
   Time1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3)
   Time2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3)

   Y = c(Time1, Time2)

   Group = c(rep("Time1", length(Time1)), rep("Time2", length(Time2)))

   Data = data.frame(Group, Y)

   library(rstatix)

   wilcox_effsize(Y ~ Group, paired=TRUE, data=Data)

      ### 0.745

   library(rcompanion)

   wilcoxonPairedRC(Data$Y, Data$Group)

      ### -1
  ```
- As a minor comment, note that the function in the *rstatix* package returns a positive value for *r* in cases where traditionally it would be reported as negative.